# Magento: updating a multiselect attribute using the attribute code

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

As the title says all I need is to update the value of an attribute using the attribute code. I know that I can usually use:

```
$product->setAtt_code();
```

and this will update the attribute with the code of attr_code. However it seems that this does not work with a multiselect attribute.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must set array with values ids

```
$product->setData('attr_code', [1, 2, 3]);
```

For example,

```
$attrCode = 'color';
$sourceModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode)->getSource();
$valueId = $sourceModel->getOptionId('red');
$product->setData($attrCode, [$valueId]);
```

Comment: Thanks $DmitryKovalev it's the correct answer and solved my issue. Does it only work on multiselect? I tried for select type and it didn't work. So for now I check the attribute's frontend type and only apply the code on multiselect attributes.

Comment: For select type: $product->setData($attrCode, $valueId);

Comment: This should be marked as the answer if it solved your issue.